# How do I send commands to a REPL before handing back to interactive mode?

Tags: bash

There are various interactive REPL like programs, sh, bc, ocaml REPL, and so on.

I can invoke them in a shell script like this: foo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
repl
```

then when I run `foo.sh` in my terminal I get an interactive repl, I can put in commands and get the results.

> How would I extend my script so that it launches the `repl` process, sends a few commands to it, then puts me back into the interactive mode

What I have tried is `echo command | repl` inside the script but it exits as soon as the command is finished.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you'll need to "remote control" the script using `expect`.

Comment: nvm solved......

Comment: The duplicate question provides one way of doing it; I don't know `expect` but there are lots of other questions about it on this site.